# Is a series (an infinite series) a sequence or a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is a beginner's question.

Recently, while watching the [*Real Analysis*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgfP3riDcrc&list=PLBh2i93oe2quABbNq4I_-hyjhW8eOdgrO&index=15) playlist proposed by *The Bright Side Of Mathematics*, it seemed to me that the notion of "series" was defined in two apparently incompatible ways: as a sequence and as a limit.

Looking at *Paul's Online Math Notes*, I find a quite unambiguous definition of a series as a limit.

The author of Paul's notes distinguishes:

1. an original sequence : $( a_n)_{n\in N}$
2. the sequence of partial sums $(s_n)_{n\in N}$ (each partial sum being the sum of the n$^{th}$ first terms of the sequence $( a_n) _ {n\in N}$)
3. the series $\sum_{i=1} ^{\infty}a_i = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n$.

However, even in *Paul's Notes*, one can read that a series "starts" at some value of $i$; which sounds strange if a series is a limit.

> In short: a) to what sort of category does the object  "series" belong? b) if a series can be seen both as a  sequence and as a limit, how are these two perspectives compatible?

Comment: Do you consider $2+2$ and $4$ to be "different"?  Certainly, you can evaluate $2+2$ and show that it is equal to $4$.  Also, when talking about $2+2$ you can talk about the first summand and the second summand which doesn't necessarily make sense if you are purely talking about the number $4$.  In the same sense, a series not only has with it knowledge of what it evaluates to, but it also retains knowledge of how we got there including but not limited to what the terms in the summation were and how we organized our thoughts in terms of how to get there.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with saying that $2+2$ and $4$ are the same.  There is nothing wrong with saying they are different either.  It depends on what you mean by "is the same."  As for "series starts at some value of $i$", yes of course.  There is a big difference between $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 0.1^n = 0.111111\cdots$ and $\sum\limits_{n=5}^\infty 0.1^n = 0.00001111\dots$.  The starting index is in reference to what the starting terms are in the sum (*equivalently, with starting index of 5 it is as though first four terms are all zero*)

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, a series does not necessarily evaluate to something. Otherwise we would not talk about divergent series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series

Comment: I agree with JMoravitz. I'd add that we define a series as a limit of certain sequence, **but** we do that to capture the elusive idea of "infinite sum". Then we extend our language (using common sense) to talk about things like "the third term of a series", "the sum of the series", "we rearrange the series terms to obtain a new series"

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Though one could, I suppose, argue that a "divergent series" is not actually a series.  There are lots of examples in mathematics where an "adjective object" is not an example of "object" (strictly speaking, a "multivalued function" is not a function; a "manifold with boundary" is not a manifold).  But this comment is really tangential to the main point of the question.

Comment: It's a fair question, but this is standard mathematical language.  I would say that it's a kind of use-mention distinction.  When we refer to "the first term of 2+2", we can't replace "2+2" with "4" in that sentence because we are referring to the first term of the expression rather than the first term of the number it represents.

Comment: @JairTaylor Looking at "referential transparency" (the name of this concept in programming languages theory), I was surprised that it seems to originate from mathematics, namely Russel and Whitehead _Principia Mathematica_. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency